# MediaWiki {{Special:PrefixIndex}} outputs "$1 - Wiki Title"

Tags: mediawiki, template, wysiwyg

I've set up some sub-pages, and trying to use the Special::PrefixIndex template to create a listing of these sub-pages as per [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subpages#Displaying_subpages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aSubpages#Displaying_subpages)

So, for example, under User:Sjones I've created User:Sjones/Drafts

When I use `{{Special:PrefixIndex/{{FULLPAGENAME}}/}}` I get `$1 - Wiki Title` instead of the a list containing User:Sjones/Drafts

I've enabled subpages for the user namespace.

When I view the page Special:PrefixIndex and enter "User:Sjones" I get the correct list.

I'm using version 1.21 on Ubuntu 12.04

I've since learned that the problem is with the TinyMCE plugin for MediaWiki - disabling the plugin restores the correct functionality.

How do I get this working with the plugin enabled?

Comment: If you found the answer, you should post it as an answer and then accept it, instead of editing your question.

Comment: I don't really feel it to be an answer - if WYSIWYG is required, then there needs to be a solution that makes this work with the WYSIWYG.